# If a date meets the date range criterion in COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I want to output the number of products that meet the two of my criteria. They are based at another sheet, and so the output number is in another sheet too. The problem I'm having is writing the date range right to actually work. I used COUNTIFS to set up a date range, but I am unsure whether the syntax even works like this.

```
╔═════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║        DATE         ║       COLOR        ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      13 Mar 18      ║        Red         ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      30 Jun 18      ║        Red         ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      07 Mar 18      ║        Blue        ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      05 Mar 18      ║        Red         ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      13 Apr 18      ║       Yellow       ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      29 Mar 18      ║       Purple       ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      11 Mar 18      ║        Red         ║
╠═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      02 Mar 18      ║        Red         ║
╚═════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

I used the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('DifferentSheet1'!A:A,IF(AND(A>3/05/2018,A<3/18/2018)),'DifferentSheet1'!B:B,"Red")
```

Expected result: `3`
Current result: `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=COUNTIFS('DifferentSheet1'!A:A, ">"&date(2018, 3, 5), 'DifferentSheet1'!A:A, "<"&date(2018, 3, 18), 'DifferentSheet1'!B:B, "Red")
```

That results in 2. Did you mean,

```
=COUNTIFS('DifferentSheet1'!A:A, ">="&date(2018, 3, 5), 'DifferentSheet1'!A:A, "<="&date(2018, 3, 18), 'DifferentSheet1'!B:B, "Red")
```

That results in 3.